# How do I create multiple lists from java Map using Stream?

Tags: java

I am new to Java 8 Stream API. I am wondering if I can create multiple lists based on the Key Value from a Map?  For Example. If my Map is

```
{"Developer", Developer; "Manager", Manager; "Lead", Lead; "Director", Director}
```

I would like to create a List of Developer, List of Manager, List of Lead and List of Director from the Map based on the Key Values.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: key and value both are string? can you please show the code with and example

Comment: Each of such lists in your example would have only one element in it, which makes it look like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Are you talking about a stream of maps? or just one map? If it is just one map, then no need for streams as maps are meant to store key-value pairs. Having a key means you can easily access the values too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)), you can generate a Map from your Key to a List of Values, provided you can compute the Key from the Value. Alternatively, you can use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)), provided you can compute both the Key and the Value from an upstream element. You probably want the version of toMap with a merge function, because that will allow you to handle multiple keys with the same value (by putting them in a list together).

**Edit:**
If you want ordering, there are overloads for [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) and [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) that allow you to provide a mapFactory (`Supplier<Map>`) , such as `TreeMap::new`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, HashMaps and HashSets don't assure any order of the keys or values...

Answer (score 0):

To invert a map, so that its distinct values become keys, and its keys are added to a collection under the corresponding value, use [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) on the map entries. It's important that the values from the original map implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly to be used as a key in the new hash table .

```
static <K, V> Map<V, Set<K>> invert(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> original) {
  return original.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      Map.Entry::getValue, 
      Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())
    ));
}
```

If you want to groups to be sorted, you can create a specialized "downstream" collector:

```
static <K, V> Map<V, SortedSet<K>> invert(
    Map<? extends K, ? extends V> original, 
    Comparator<? super K> order) {

  Collector<K, ?, SortedSet<K>> toSortedSet = 
     Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(order));
  return original.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      Map.Entry::getValue, 
      Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toSortedSet)
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code for the same by using Collectors.groupBy() :

```
                List<Details> employeeList = Arrays.asList(new Details("Pratik", "Developer"), new Details("Rohit", "Manager"), new Details("Sonal", "Developer"), new Details("Sagar", "Lead"), new Details("Sanket", "Lead"));       

                Map<String, List<Details>> collect = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x-> x.getDesignation()));
                System.out.println("Checking details "+ collect);
```